# Boost Property Maps - put_get_helper, keys are passed by value

Tags: c++, boost

I require a property-map which returns passed key (itself or a 'part' of it) as mapped value. For this purpose I wrote another helper since boost::put_get_helper's put function passes keys by value.

```
// Pasted as a reminder (from boost)
template <class PropertyMap, class Reference, class K, class V>
inline void 
put(const put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>& pa, K k, const V& v) 
{ 
  static_cast<const PropertyMap&>(pa)[k] = v; 
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this by not introducing another custom helper ? (may be there already something similar exists in boost)